# How do I select the text from cursor to white space with vi script?

Tags: vim

```
expand('<cword>')
```

The above can select the word from cursor, but I want to select more, that is the text delimited by the cursor and the first white space.

How to do that in vim script?

**UPDATE**

I'm seeking a flexible way to do string manipulation in vi script.

Comment: Did you try `<cWORD>`?

Comment: @romainl, that seems to be working, but is there a more flexible way to specify a regex so that I can match the text as I like?

Comment: You should add more background to your question.

Comment: @romainl,I'm quite experienced in manipulating string in various programing languages, but doesn't find a flexible way to do it in vi script yet..

Comment: That's not the kind of background I was asking for. What is your goal? How do you plan to execute the function/command? Did you read `:help functions`?

Comment: A little offtopic, why don't you use vim ?

Answer (score 2):

Enter the command `vf`

1. `v`: visual selection
2. `f`: find
3. : space

Please note that this way the space is selected as well.

Comment: This seems not working in ` Vi IMproved 7.3`.Just to make things clearer,I need to pass the selected text to another function.

Answer (score 0):

1. `v`: start visual selection
2. `t<space>`: go to next occurrence of the input character (in this case )